# Delay event handler without freezing UI thread

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to add a 2 second delay for a program I am making in c# and I do not want to totally  lock up the main thread because I want a progress bar to still move and then 2 seconds later, I want the whole program to exit. How will I do this?

Comment: Timers are useful here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Task.Delay`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194873(v=vs.110).aspx) with an async event handler:

```
public async void SomeEventhandler(object obj, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Delay(2000);
    // Do stuff after delay.
}
```